# How to set the equivalent of Jetty's "maxFormContentSize" in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, jetty

We're migrating a project from a classic war project to a Spring Boot application. The old project was using Jetty and when starting the Jetty JVM we supplied the `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=5000000` parameter to limit the max size of form uploads. We want the same limit in our Spring Boot application. But I'm a bit confused since there are many properties to choose from in Spring Boot, for example:

```
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size
spring.servlet.multipart.fileSizeThreshold
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size
```

There could of course be more properties in the same vane that I don't know about.

My question is: What's the equivalent of `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=5000000` in Spring Boot *when using the embedded tomcat web server*? We're using Spring Boot 2.5.6 (but we will upgrade to 2.6.x) and we're using the standard embedded Tomcat web server with blocking IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the spring documentation the [`server.jetty.max-http-form-post-size`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.jetty.max-http-form-post-size) is equivalent to the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize` property and defines the *Maximum size of the form content in any HTTP post request*.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for the equivalent setting for the _tomcat_ web server.

Comment: @Johan You are welcome, then `server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size` included in your post sounds more convenient, all the server properties are defined in the link I posted.